# React menu item hover

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am trying React MobX on hover over a list item. Here is my code

```
export default observer( 
class SidebarContent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.store.fetchSources() 
  }  

  toggleHover(){
    this.props.store.hover = !this.props.store.hover;
  }

  getArticles(src) {
    this.props.store.fetchArticles(src); 
  }

 render() {
  const style1 = this.props.style ? {...styles.sidebar, ...this.props.style} : styles.sidebar;
  const { sources, hover  } = this.props.store

    var linkStyle;
    if (this.props.store.hover) {
      linkStyle = {backgroundColor: 'black'}
    } else {
      linkStyle = {backgroundColor: 'white'}
    }

  const links = sources.map( (src,index) => (
    <a key={index} href='javascript:;' style={styles.sidebarLink} onClick={this.getArticles.bind(this, src.id)} >
          <span style={linkStyle}  onMouseEnter={this.toggleHover.bind(this)} onMouseLeave={this.toggleHover.bind(this)}     >
            <img className="ui-avaatar image" src='{ src.urlsToLogos.small }' />
            <span className="side-news-item"> {src.name} </span>  
          </span>    
    </a>
  )) 
  return (
    <MaterialTitlePanel title="Menu" style={style1}>
      <div style={styles.content}>
        <div style={styles.divider} />
        {links}
      </div>
    </MaterialTitlePanel>
  );
  }
}
);
const styles = {
  sidebar: {
    width: 256,
    height: '100%',
  },
  sidebarLink: {
    display: 'block',
    padding: '16px 0px',
    color: '#757575',
    textDecoration: 'none',
  },
  divider: {
    margin: '8px 0',
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#757575',
  },
  content: {
    padding: '16px',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
};
```

`this.props.store.hover` is a observable. 
The problem is that when mouse over one item, all of the items get the hover effect. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not set Component's props directly, set it on upper Component.
or you could use state feature, and always use setState() to change state.

write an subcomponent to control the Button State

code below maybe help

```js
class SidebarContent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.store.fetchSources() 
  }  

  getArticles(src) {
    this.props.store.fetchArticles(src); 
  }

 render() {


  const links = sources.map( (src,index) => <Button />); 
  return (
    <MaterialTitlePanel title="Menu" style={style1}>
      <div style={styles.content}>
        <div style={styles.divider} />
        {links}
      </div>
    </MaterialTitlePanel>
  );
  }
}

class Button extends React.Component {

  toggleHover(){
    this.setState({
      hover: !this.state.hover,
    });
  }


  render() {
    const style1 = this.props.style ? {...styles.sidebar, ...this.props.style} : styles.sidebar;
    const { sources  } = this.props.store
    const { hover } = this.state;

    var linkStyle;
    if (hover) {
      linkStyle = {backgroundColor: 'black'}
    } else {
      linkStyle = {backgroundColor: 'white'}
    }
  
    return (
        <a key={index} href='javascript:;' style={styles.sidebarLink} onClick={this.getArticles.bind(this, src.id)} >
          <span style={linkStyle}  onMouseEnter={this.toggleHover.bind(this)} onMouseLeave={this.toggleHover.bind(this)}     >
            <img className="ui-avaatar image" src='{ src.urlsToLogos.small }' />
            <span className="side-news-item"> {src.name} </span>  
          </span>    
    </a>
    );
  }

}


const styles = {
  sidebar: {
    width: 256,
    height: '100%',
  },
  sidebarLink: {
    display: 'block',
    padding: '16px 0px',
    color: '#757575',
    textDecoration: 'none',
  },
  divider: {
    margin: '8px 0',
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#757575',
  },
  content: {
    padding: '16px',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```